# How to change Django default message in django.contrib.auth.form

Tags: django, django-authentication

I used Django default AuthenticationForm for login.
Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    AuthenticationForm,PasswordResetForm,UsernameField
)
class ProfiledAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(
        label=_("username"),
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True,'placeholder': 'username'}),
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}),
    )
```

When the login is failed, an default alert is appeared.
I need to customize the alert.
How should I handle it?

Comment: Specifically, which error message do you wish to change?

Comment: "Please enter the correct user name and password. Both fields are case sensitive."
I need to change this to another sentence

Answer (score 2):

You can change the message overwriting the `error_messages` property in your inherit class.

```py
class ProfiledAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _("My custom error message"),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }
```